# How can I concatenate arrays of arrays index by index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have two or more n-dimenisonal arrays, each of which contains also arrays, how con I concatenate all of them index by index?

An example would be:

```
A = np.array([[[1,2], [3,4]], [[4,5,6], [1]]])
B = np.array([[[10,20], [3,9]], [[7,5], [2]]])
```

and i would like to get

```
C = np.array([[[1,2,10,20], [3,4,3,9]], [[4,5,6,7,5], [1,2]]])
```

Comment: You should correct the description.  Your arrays contain lists, not arrays.  In this case that distinction is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since your inner lists are of different lengths, you've ended up building 2×2 arrays of lists:

```
>>> A.shape
(2, 2)
```

But in numpy, `+` acts elementwise, and on lists, `+` does concatenation. So:

```
>>> C = A + B
>>> C
array([[[1, 2, 10, 20], [3, 4, 3, 9]],
       [[4, 5, 6, 7, 5], [1, 2]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is a neat, but somewhat unique, interaction of 2 different uses of `+`.  If, for example, the elements of `A` and `B` were arrays themselves, this would not work.